# Adding count to ggseqplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, sequence

I am using the ggseqplot package to visualize sequential data, however, I cannot add a count label to each stack. Following is my code:

```
ggseqdplot(biofam.seq, border = T) +
  scale_fill_discrete_sequential("PuBuGn")+
  scale_x_discrete() +
  labs(x = "Path Number") +
  theme(legend.position = "right") +
  theme_minimal()
```

This sample dataset can be used:

```
data(biofam)
biofam <- biofam[sample(nrow(biofam),300),]
biofam.lab <- c("Parent", "Left", "Married", "Left+Marr",
                "Child", "Left+Child", "Left+Marr+Child", "Divorced")
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam, 10:25, labels=biofam.lab)
```

[image]

How can I add a count data label to each stack of this plot.

Answer (score 0):

Including count labels in a dplot is unconventional, because in most instances the resulting plots are quite crowded. This is also true for the example data you used but, of course, this might be different in your own application.

As virtually no one uses count labels, this option is not implemented in `ggseqdplot`, but you can add another plot layer containing the labels using `geom_text`. For this purpose, we have to generate an additional data set containing the labels (state frequencies) and their positions on the x and y axes.

In the following code, I first extract the state frequencies using `table` and then reshape the data into the long (tidy) format required by ggplot. If you save the plot generated with `ggseqdplot` as an object (`p`) you can inspect the data underlying the plot (`p$data`). This gives you an idea of the required data structure for your count label data. Once the data are in the right shape, you can add the label plot layer. Note that I only display count labels if states with a frequency higher than 10.

```r
# load required libraries 

library(TraMineR)
library(ggseqplot)
library(tidyverse)

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Example data
data(biofam)
set.seed(10)
biofam <- biofam[sample(nrow(biofam),300),]
biofam.lab <- c("Parent", "Left", "Married", "Left+Marr",
                "Child", "Left+Child", "Left+Marr+Child", "Divorced")
biofam.seq <- seqdef(biofam, 10:25, labels=biofam.lab)

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Render & save dplot

p <- ggseqdplot(biofam.seq, border = T) +
  scale_x_discrete() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") 
#> Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will
#> replace the existing scale.

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Table with state frequencies
state.freqs <- map_dfc(biofam.seq, table) |>
  map_dfc(as.numeric) |> 
  mutate(state = row_number(), .before = 1)

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Reshape & prepare data for plot
label.data <- state.freqs |> 
  pivot_longer(cols = -1,
               names_to = "x",
               values_to = "label") |>
  group_by(state) |> 
  mutate(x = row_number() |> factor()) |> 
  ungroup() |> 
  filter(label != 0) |> 
  mutate(state = factor(state, labels = stlab(biofam.seq))) |> 
  group_by(x) |> 
  mutate(y = cumsum(label/sum(label)))

# Have a look at the data  
label.data
#> # A tibble: 92 × 4
#> # Groups:   x [16]
#>    state  x     label     y
#>    <fct>  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 Parent 1       296 0.987
#>  2 Parent 2       285 0.95 
#>  3 Parent 3       281 0.937
#>  4 Parent 4       269 0.897
#>  5 Parent 5       249 0.83 
#>  6 Parent 6       222 0.74 
#>  7 Parent 7       189 0.63 
#>  8 Parent 8       162 0.54 
#>  9 Parent 9       135 0.45 
#> 10 Parent 10      112 0.373
#> # … with 82 more rows

# ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

# Add labels to original plot
# We only show labels for states with more than 10 occurences 

p +
  geom_text(data = label.data |> filter(label > 10),
            aes(x = x, y = y, label = label),
            nudge_y = -.02, size = 3)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-10-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>